# How to save variables to a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm very new to JQuery, JS and JSON

I'm trying to just get a basic save file created using this code:

```
<script>
var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;

// Storing data:
myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
$.setJSON("testJSON", myJSON);

// Retrieving data:
text = $.getJSON("testJSON.json");
obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name;
```

I'm pretty sure $.setJSON doesn't exist but I can't find what I use to set variables. Eventually I want to set up loops and save text from a textarea in a json file.

I know this isn't a great thing to set up and that I should probably set this up with php and sql. But this only going to be used by 2 users and it wont be simultaneously.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? JavaScript does not have access to the user's local filesystem so you can't just _write a file_. You can prompt the user to download something though

Comment: First of all, `getJSON` doesn't return text; it returns a promise that can resolve to text (or to already parsed data). Secondly, while a web server like Apache httpd can read a file for you, it will not write a file for you; you need to have something at the server to accept posted data and save it to a file.  It might be PHP, or a CGI script, or a proxy to another process in a language of your choice. You would initiate a request to this active component, typically with `$.ajax`, to ask it to save something for you.

Comment: @Phil So there is no way to auto-generate a save file on a single device, also this thread is kind of linked to the last one,(that you answered)

Comment: You can use cookies or local storage to store data at the client side. Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: Like I said, you can prompt the user to save a file but the triggering of that action and the file's destination is up to them; you cannot do this programatically

Comment: @Arshad I have the HTML page I'm using on a basic xampp server and I want to stay as basic as I can as far as languages used and complexity. I want to have a text area that a user can type into that is cached on the server and then called back up when the page loads.

Comment: @STOAM, You can use cookies in this case if it is not sensitive data. You can access this in server side as well as client side.

Comment: @Arshad if I use cookies will I have the ability to show the data gathered by the cookies to other users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do regarding file operations.

#### Prompt the user for download

Create an anchor with the `download` attribute and a [*data-uri*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) `href` for the JSON.

```js
const data = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let dl = document.createElement('a')
  dl.download = 'test.json' // target filename
  dl.href = `data:application/json;charset=utf-8,${JSON.stringify(data)}`
  dl.click()
})
```

```html
<button id="download" type="button">Save</button>
```

You may run into URI length problems with this depending on the size of your data but considering you can base64-encode a several MB image into a *data-uri* easily, I probably wouldn't worry.

#### Allow the user to upload a file

Listen for *input* or *change* events on an `<input type="file">` and read the file data

```js
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('input', e => {
  let file = e.currentTarget.files[0]
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = e => {
    try {
      let obj = JSON.parse(e.target.result)
      
      // congrats, you now have an object from the file
      
      document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('JSON parsing error', err.message)
    }
  }
  reader.onerror = e => {
    console.error('PANIC!', e)
  }
  reader.readAsText(file)
})
```

```html
<dl>
<dt><label for="upload">Upload your <code>.json</code> file</label></dt>
<dd><input type="file" id="upload"></dd>
</dl>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```

There's a lot of error checking omitted from this answer so I suggest you read up on using the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API for more details.

Answer (score 0):

JS will not access computer except **some others**

You should (***not should this is just another way to store your json since js cant access through folders anyway***) store your json into `localStorage.setItem(keytolaterretreive,yourJson)`

You can later retreive it `localStorage.getItem(keytolaterretreive)` this will return your desired json

Example:

```
myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
localStorage.setItem("myJson",myJSON);
retreivedJson = localStorage.getItem("myJson");
console.log(retreivedJson);<-- your json will be consoled
```

For more information about [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score -1):

Javascript in the browser does not have API access to the underlying file system, so you will not be able to save a JSON file this way. The only thing you would be able to do is to aggregate the user data into a Form and Post the data to a server side API via AJAX.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) documentation should help you understand FormData and how to send it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse the `.json` text into JavaScript. [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Then you can get at the properties.

> ```
> var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
> obj = JSON.parse(json);
>
> console.log(obj.count);
> // expected output: 42
>
> console.log(obj.result);
> // expected output: true
> ```